# get date from google sheet in data frame convert each date in integer

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

**What do I want to achieve?**

get the date from the google sheet in the dataframe and convert the dataframe each date in integer.

**If this is better with JSON let me know**

get a date from google sheet in JSON each date in integer.

**why I am doing it**

```
#this code takes date month and year in integer format SO!
from QuantLib import *
valuation_date = Date(22, 8, 2018)
print(valuation_date+2)
```

**Output:**

```
August 24th, 2018
```

**My solution.**

But I want something better. and there is one problem also.

```
Date_df = df['Date line 6']

date_lst = []
month_lst = []
year_lst = []

for i in Date_df:
    date_lst.append(int(i[0:2])) 
    month_lst.append(int(i[3:4]))
    year_lst.append(int(i[-4:]))
```

**The Problem In Above Code**

```
 date_lst.append(int(i[0:2]))
```

Here if the date is 12 then it's ok because 0 and 1 two indexes are appended to date_lstbut if a date is 8 which is single in that case output is 8/(**because at index 1 values is /**) which cant be converted to int and produce an error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a dataframe, I am Working with JSON.

First Get data from the sheet and convert it into JSON

```
json_data = pd.DataFrame(sheet.get_all_records()).to_json()
```

Write data in JSON file for Later USE

```
 with open('sheet_json_data.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json_data)
```

Reading JSON File and Convert It In Pyhton Obj

```
with open('sheet_json_data.json') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)
```

Here convert JSON to Dictionary  `json.load(f)`

Here create DateTime with string and get int type class.

str_date = json_data['Date line 6'][str(1)]
date_time = dt.datetime.strptime(str_date, '%m/%d/%Y')

```
print(type(date_time.day))
print(date_time.month)
print(date_time.year)
```